# OpenCart product link tab not save my changes

Tags: php, opencart

i'm trying update a product information on "Link" Tab, but, after press "save" the changes are not applied to the product. shows no error message, nothing happens, just redirects to the products page again. anyone here can help me? i'm trying solve it, but are hard.

appear to be a problem after install a theme on admin panel, maybe at file:

/admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl

here the source code:
http://pastebin.com/W7VerUbh

screenshot of dev-tools:
[image: input hidden with value "undefined"]

Comment: Could You be so kind, and provide us with some code? E.g. that used for "saving" and where the redirect occurs?

Comment: i think it happen after install a new theme to my admin panel

Comment: the source code: http://pastebin.com/W7VerUbh

Comment: I do not see any problem here in template. Could You post the code from controller?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved, it was a JSON inserted by theme, which removed field values.the JSON was at the end of the script, and inserted a invalid value "option_value" at fields